# Cannot load translation from database in symfony 4.3.3

Tags: php, symfony, translation

i'm trying to load translations from database in Symfony 4. The Translator instance doesn't call the custom loader i wrote using this tutorial (https://medium.com/@andrew72ru/store-translation-messages-in-database-in-symfony-3f12e579df74).

I created dummy files in the `/translation` folder (messages.it.db) to trigger the loader but it doesn't get called.

**services.yaml**

```
parameters:
    locales: ['it','en']
    db_i18n.entity: App\Entity\Translation
 services:
    translation.loader.db:
        class: App\Loader\DbLoader
        arguments:
          - '@service_container'
          - '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager'
        tags:
          - { name: translation.loader, alias: db}
```

**DbLoader.php**

```
namespace App\Loader;


use Creative\DbI18nBundle\Interfaces\EntityInterface;
use Creative\DbI18nBundle\Interfaces\TranslationRepositoryInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\LoaderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\MessageCatalogue;

class DbLoader implements LoaderInterface
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private $doctrine;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $entityClass;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container, EntityManagerInterface $doctrine)
    {
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
        $this->entityClass = $container->getParameter('db_i18n.entity');
    }

    public function load($resource, $locale, $domain = 'messages')
    {
        $messages = $this->getRepository()->findByDomainAndLocale($domain, $locale);
        $values = array_map(static function (EntityInterface $entity) {
            return $entity->getTranslation();
        }, $messages);

        $catalogue = new MessageCatalogue($locale, [
            $domain => $values
        ]);

        return $catalogue;
    }

    public function getRepository(): TranslationRepositoryInterface
    {
        return $this->doctrine->getRepository($this->entityClass);
    }
}
```

[Here's my translation table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2TG5.png)

Here is the test code i'm using to call the Translator

**TestController.php**

```
class TestController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/test", name="test")
     */
    public function index(TranslatorInterface $translator)
    {
        $translator->trans('prova', [], 'messages', 'it');

        return new Response();
    }
}
```

The result is supposed to be "prova it" but I get "prova" instead, which is the key of the translation. I tried to put a `dd()` on the DbLoader constructor and it's never been called.

I also have in my project Api Platform, but i don't think it's causing this problem.

Comment: I am not sure but maybe the problem in your service.yml file. It can bee because you format is incorrect. Space before "services:" keyword

Comment: There was no mistake in my service.yaml file. I wrongly put a space there while coping my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue.

By using `dd()` on my Translator instance i discovered that Symfony wasn't loading my translation files correctly. Looking through the properties i noticed the path of my translation files were not correct.

I placed them in `src/Resources/translations` instead and then it worked!